# Should internally generated resets be asserted synchronously or asynchronously?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, reset

In my design, I have a subsystem that needs to be reset when a specific condition is met. **The condition depends only signals that are outputs of flip-flops.** I am considering these 3 approaches to design the logic:

### Approach 1:

`reset_int = (condition) || reset;`

`reset_int` is the internal reset, `condition` denotes a boolean condition and `reset` is the external asynchronous reset. `reset_int` is the asynchronous reset to the subsystem.

In my subsystem the logic is:

```
always @(posedge reset_int)
  if (reset_int) 
     <reset statements>
```

### Approach 2:

A synchronous "clear" input to the subsystem, in addition to the asynchronous reset. I then set the clear in combinational logic:

`clear = (condition);`

In my subsystem the logic is:

```
always @(posedge clk or posedge reset)
  if (reset) 
     <reset statements>
  else begin
     if (clear)
       <reset statements>
```

### Approach 3:

A synchronous "clear" input to the subsystem, with no asynchronous reset. I then set the clear in combinational logic as follows:

`clear = (condition) || reset;`

In my subsystem the logic is:

```
always @(posedge clk)
  if (clear) 
     <reset statements>
```

---

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each approach? Is there a better approach?

Comment: If you don't synchronize the reset (preferably with a double FF) there could be a hazard when it is released. Some parts of the logic may catch the release on one clock edge other parts on the subsequent clock edge.

Comment: @KevinWhite thanks for pointing this. I have edited my answer to include this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In the case of a reset being generated by a set of internal conditions, a synchronous reset is recommended for these types of designs because it will filter the logic equation glitches between clocks.](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2002SJ_Resets.pdf)

Approach 1 is ruled out because it would propagate glitches on the logic equation.

[Approach 3 is fine as long as a pulse stretcher to guarantee a reset pulse width wide enough to ensure reset is present during an active edge of the clock is used.](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2002SJ_Resets.pdf)

Approach 2 does not need the pulse stretcher since it has an asynchronous reset in addition to the clear input. That's the reason I prefer the second approach.

A reset synchronizer circuit is a must for asynchronous resets.